# Is MahApps.Metro needed for Windows 8.1 WPF app?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am developing WPF app using Windows 7 and using MahApps.Metro library for Metro style UI. Now the default WPF app running in Windows 8.1 provides the same Metro Style, do I need to use MahApps for the styling?

Is there any advantages for MahApps.Metro over default style? I don't have Windows 8.1 machine to compare.

Thanks.

Comment: I develop for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, and I just use XAML and C# in VS with no third-party software.

Comment: Do you get the same style with default XAML like MahApps.Metro?

Comment: I have never used MahApps.Metro.  The app is set to use the default Dark theme, but I override most colors and built my own GUI and everything from scratch in a blank app.

Comment: @Hosch250: He is talking about WPF, not about the Windows Store App.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage Oh.  I thought MahApps.Metro was for "metro" (now modern) apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mah Apps provide a custom style on top of your WPF default style regardless of operating system. You said you want Metro Style in your WPF application. So you should still use MahApps in Windows 8.1 also. As I know Windows 8.1 desktop mode doesn't look like Metro Style as MahApps does.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing two different things. MahApps.Metro is a styling toolkit for WPF applications.

When you're saying

> Now the default WPF app running in Windows 8.1 provides the same Metro Style, do I need to use MahApps for the styling?

you're not using WPF, but "Modern UI/Metro/Modern Apps" on the Windows Runtime (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime), which have nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: I am not developing universal app which is different fro WPF. Modern Apps aka Universal Apps are developed only for WinRT platform whose API is subset of WPF. Universal apps will run in a sandbox just like browser.    My question is if Windows 8.1 provides the Metro style by default to all apps, then what is the advantage of using MahApps in Windows 8.1?

Comment: Windows 8.1 doesn't provide MahApps.Metro by default. MahApps.Metro is an independent open source project and is in no way sponsored by Microsoft.